# Hide TODO tag in Visual Studio Task List

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Our codebase has a bunch of TODO comments that no one will ever fix and that the boss refuses to remove.

I would like to hide the TODO's from the Visual Studio task list and just show my custom MEDO tags.

It appears that Visual studio will not let you remove the TODO tag from the task list. The remove button is grayed out for TODO. (You can remove all the other default tags, just not TODO.)

Does anyone know some kind of hack or something that will allow me to remove them anyway? Maybe editing some config file somewhere?

Answer (score 11):

As you've discovered, Visual Studio won't allow you to modify the TODO token, but you can trick it by using the Priority settings to filter it out.

First, set your MEDO token to "High Priority" as shown here:

[image: Changing MEDO token to high priority]

Then filter the Task List window to only show high priority items.  (The filter button is hard to see on that column - you may need to widen it a bit.)

[image: Filtering Task List to show only high priority items]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am currently doing, but it's still annoying to have 100 TODO items in the list that I don't care about.

Answer (score -2):

By default, Visual Studio includes the following tokens: HACK, TODO, UNDONE, NOTE.

All you need to do is to remove the TODO from these list of predefined tokens. (you can create your own tokens as well)

On the Tools menu, choose Options.
Open the Environment folder and then choose Task List and then delete the TODO token.

So now you will continue to have TODO comments in your codebase but they will not show in your task list.

Comment: You can remove all but TODO
When you try to remove TODO, the remove button gets grayed out

Comment: This does not work in Visual Studio 2017.  Did you try this in an earlier version of Visual Studio?